# How can I edit List<users> elements and show the changes in a WPF list?

Tags: c#, wpf, list

Is there a way in C# using WPF to edit a current list? For example, if I made a form with a user's personal information and then I want to edit one of those fields, is there a way of doing that?
if so, how do you do that?

So far I have a class called users that has different variables and then it makes those variables into a list of objects.

```
public class Users
{
  public string sFullName {get; set;}
  public string sPhoneNumber {get; set;}
  public int iAge {get; set;}
}

public class userObject
{
  public static List<Users> lstUsers {get; set;}

  static UserObject()
  {
    lstUsers = new List<Users>();
  }
}

public static void AddNewUser(string fullName, string phoneNumber, int age)
{
  lstUsers.Add(new Users{sFullName = fullName, sPhoneNumber = phoneNumber, iAge = age});
}
```

Is there a way to change the information added above with the following code?

```
public static void EditCurrentUser(int age)
{
  //sudo code
  lstUser.Edit(iAge = age where sFullName  = "bob"); // change iAge to the current or most resent list?
}
```

Comment: You have a naming issue here. `Users` should be called `User` as it only represents one user. I found it confusing to read.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do in-place edit using LINQ:

```
lstUsers.Where(u => u.sFullName == "bob").Select(u => u.iAge = age).ToList();
```

**OR**

Can do using traditional approach:

```
foreach (Users user in lstUsers)
{
   if (user.sFullName == "bob")
   {
      user.iAge = age;
   }
}
```

Comment: @L.B - It does work. Have you tried it? That's in place edit and have used it million of times.

Comment: this works great! i didnt try the second approach but the first one worked wonders! thank you so much

Answer (score 0):

Suppose you have `ItemsSource = "{Binding lstUsers}"` and in `ItemTemplate` for instance `TextBox` `Text="{Binding sFullName, Mode = TwoWay}"`.

Mode `TwoWay` or `OneWayToSource` enables to change source of binding.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at [Linq](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397933.aspx)

```
public static void EditCurrentUser(int age)
{
    var user = lstUser.FirstOrDefault(u => u.sFullName == "bob");
    if (user != null)
    {
        user.iAge = age
    }
}
```